How can I search/replace paragraph markers in MSOffice on the web?
With the fat-client Office solution, I could always use ^p and ^l in the search and replace fields to indicate paragraph and line breaks respectively.
However, we're now using Linux as the underlying OS so that we're forced to use the web browser version for Word.
When I enter ^p in the search box, it insists that it cannot find any paragraph breaks, despite the fact there are hundreds of them in there.
Is there a way to do this replacement with the web version of Word or, failing that, is there a way I can paste code from the clipboard with newlines rather than paragraph breaks? It's basically a huge amount of code that I want single-spaced and converted to Courier (I have no issues with the latter need).

Do you have the free Word Online, or paid Microsoft Office 365 Word Online? The free one is a limited version of Word that is missing a lot of features/options. If you do not want to pay, perhaps consider using Google Docs instead of Word Online, since it gives you their full version (though which might be limited in some ways), or use LibreOffice installed on Linux.

AFAIK a newline also does not work. (Discovered while working on an Office-JS addin for Word - looking for a newline does work with the windows desktop version of Word but does not work with the web version. In fact, AFAICS there is no way currently to find anything that spans two paragraphs using the web-based version of Find.
